# Magento Error: Processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

Tags: magento2, error

I've ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and now when I am opening localhost/admin. Here it is showing this error.

`There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number: 1320359676`

**Here is what Log report says?**

```
a:4:{i:0;s:664:"Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Mageplaza_Core data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Smartwave_Core data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Smartwave_Filterproducts data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Smartwave_Megamenu data: current version - none, required version - 2.1.0
Smartwave_Porto data: current version - none, required version - 2.5.0
Smartwave_Socialfeeds data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0";i:1;s:828:"#0 
C:\wamp64\www\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator-
>aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure),Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#1 C:\wamp64\www\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26):
Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#2 C:\wamp64\www\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 C:\wamp64\www\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#4 C:\wamp64\www\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#5 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Please give me a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` as the error message suggests.
You could clear the cache just to be safe, but I don't think it's needed.
If you deleted some modules manually, delete them from `app/etc/modules/config.php`